# Как посмотреть global default timeout setting?

Tags: python

Есть необходимость использовать:

```
class poplib.POP3(host[, port[, timeout]])
```

В [описании](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/poplib.html) написано, что если `timeout` не указан, используется стандартное значение.
Как и где посмотреть `global default timeout setting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если параметр не установлен, то будет использоваться значение из

```
socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
```

Довольно нелогично. Я бы на вашем месте выставлял бы его руками.

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность. Использую python 2.5.2 где параметра timeout - нет, поэтому хотелось понять какое всетаки значение сейчас используется.